# Use jQuery to return only the first table cell value following a selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

http://jsfiddle.net/nealjones/xpyhxg0t/1/
I'm relatively new to jQuery and regrettably have been stumped on this issue for days.

If you open up the terminal and view the console, when either of the bottom two boxes are checked, it outputs ALL values, I need it to output only the ONE value that is associated with that checkbox (on the same row).

My purpose is to ultimately insert an additional row on a table within a Django Admin page which will display the total and average of different columns.

I imagine this simply comes down to properly navigating the DOM, but like I mentioned, I am currently stumped. Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

HTML:

```
<div class="results">
    <table id="result_list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="action-checkbox-column">
                    <div class="text"><span><input type="checkbox" id="action-toggle" /></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="sortable column-status">
                    <div class="text"><a href="?o=1">Status</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="sortable column-pool">
                    <div class="text"><a href="?o=2">Pool</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="sortable column-_id">
                    <div class="text"><a href="?o=3"> id</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="sortable column-number">
                    <div class="text"><a href="?o=4"> Number</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="sortable column-id_number">
                    <div class="text"><a href="?o=5"> id number</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="sortable column-property_type">
                    <div class="text"><a href="?o=6">type</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="sortable column-county">
                    <div class="text"><a href="?o=7">County</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="sortable column-_amount">
                    <div class="text"><a href="?o=8"> amount</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="column-rad">
                    <div class="text"><span>Rad</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="column-interest_rate">
                    <div class="text"><span>Int. Rate</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody">
            <tr class="row1">
                <td class="action-checkbox">
                    <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="4" />
                </td>
                <th class="field-status"><a href="page">Open</a>
                </th>
                <td class="field-pool">1</td>
                <td class="field-id">1</td>
                <td class="field-number">2</td>
                <td class="field-id_number">2</td>
                <td class="field-type">1</td>
                <td class="field-county">aln</td>
                <td class="field-amount">(None)</td>
                <td class="field-rad">22244444444444</td>
                <td class="field-interest_rate">50%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row2">
                <td class="action-checkbox">
                    <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                </td>
                <th class="field-status"><a href="page2">closed</a>
                </th>
                <td class="field-pool">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="field-id">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="field-number">1</td>
                <td class="field-id_number">1</td>
                <td class="field-property">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="field-county">clark</td>
                <td class="field-amount">(None)</td>
                <td class="field-rad">$111.00</td>
                <td class="field-interest_rate">10%</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $(".results").click(function () {
            if (":checked") {
                $('.field-rad').each(function () {
                    var sstr = $(this).html();
                    var nnum = Number(sstr.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g, ""));
                    console.log(nnum);
                });

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Not at all clear what you are expecting this code to do. `if (":checked")` is not a valid test for anything

Comment: Just one explanation -> you need to get FIRST CELL or first ROW (closest row to the selected/checked checkbox)? And do you need click event on main div, really?

Comment: demo link is now invalid

Comment: @nevermind I need to get the first row. I will change that click event, I just figured I'd work from the outside in till I got basic functionality working.

Comment: @NealJones, is this it? http://jsfiddle.net/xpyhxg0t/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      sstr = $(this).parent().parent().find('.field-rad').text();
      var nnum = Number(sstr.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g, ""));
      console.log(nnum);
    }
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xpyhxg0t/4/

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what you want the code to do exactly but will provide conceptual row isolation based on checkbox change event.

Within an event handler `this` is the element that was acted upon. You can then use traverses from that element to isolate row instances

```
$('.action-checkbox-column :checkbox').change(function(){
   // within event handler, "this" is element acted upon
   var amIchecked = this.checked;
   // isolate the row instance
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
   // get field-rad value on this row by using find()
   var rad = $row.find('.field-rad').val();


});
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped me understand things a little bit better.